# Why cannot I get the value of $form_state['value']['ma_so_thue'] when the form is submitted?

Tags: 7, forms

I created a module which uses the following code.

```php
function module_template_menu() {
  $items = array();

  $items['them-noi-dung'] = array(
    'title' => t('Khai báo hóa chất'),
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('module_template_select_form',2),
    'access callback' => true,
  );

  return $items;
}

function module_template_select_form($form, &$form_state) {
  $form = array();

  $form['select'] = array(
    '#type' => 'radios',
    '#title' =>'Lựa chọn hình thức khai báo',
    '#options' => array(
      '0' => t('Khai báo lần đầu'),
      '1' => t('Đã từng khai báo')
    ),
    '#default_value' => '0', 
  );

  $form['ma_so_thue'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#size' => '20',
    '#title' => 'Vui lòng nhập vào Mã Số Thuế',
    '#states' => array(
      'visible' => array(':radio[name="select"]' => array('value'=>'1')),
    ),
  );

  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Tiếp tục'),
  );

  return $form;
}
    
function module_template_select_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  $select = $form_state['values']['select'];
  $masothue = $form_state['values']['ma_so_thue'];

  if (isset($select)) {
    $masothue = $form_state['values']['ma_so_thue'];
    $form_state['redirect'] = 'node/add/khai-bao-hoa-chat';
  }
}
    
function module_template_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  $masothue = $form_state['values']['ma_so_thue'];

  if ($form_id == 'khai_bao_hoa_chat_node_form') {
    $form['field_ten_to_chuc']['und'][0]['value']['#default_value'] = $masothue;
  }
}

function module_template_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  $items = array();

  $items['khai_bao_hoa_chat_node_form'] = array(
    'render element' => 'form',
    'template' => 'khai-bao-hoa-chat',
    'path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'module_template'),
  );

  return $items;
}
```

Why cannot I get the value of `$form_state['value']['ma_so_thue']` in `module_template_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id)` when the form is submitted?

Answer (score 3):

The code you are showing is wrong for two reasons:

- `hook_form_alter()` is invoked for every form Drupal is showing; this includes Drupal core forms, as well as forms implemented by third-party modules. It is not invoked for the forms of your own module. So, you first need to check for which form the hook is being invoked, then you can access the form fields the form of your module is using.
- `hook_form_alter()` is not invoked when the form is submitted, but before the form is rendered. So you cannot use `$masothue = $form_state['values']['ma_so_thue'];` there. You need to add a new submission handler from `hook_form_alter()`, and in that submission handler you can get the submitted values, but then you cannot alter the default value for a form field in a submission handler.

As side note, the first argument of `t()` needs to be a string containing an English phrase, since the purpose of `t()` is to translate a phrase shown in the user interface from English to the language set for the site. The value of `$items['them-noi-dung']['title']` doesn't need to be a translated string, as Drupal core will translate it, but it still needs to contain an English phrase.

Answer (score 0):

Because there is no `$form_state['values']['ma_so_thue']` in `hook_form_alter` (even taught you have Ajax or `#rebuild` it in form validation or you are in edit mode),
if you are in  edit mode in `hook_form_alter` you can get value  from `$form['ma_so_thue']`. ( [dpm](https://api.drupal.org/api/devel/devel.module/function/dpm/7) it and see what you have there, it will be something like  `$form['ma_so_thue']['und']['0']['#value']` )

Comment: No. I want get value $form['ma_so_thue'] to module_template_form_alter() when submit module_template_select_form()

Comment: @LêQuangTú please tell me more, you want get `ma_so_thue'` value in submit of your form ? or in `form_alter` ?

Comment: i have ajax with dropdownlist in a form alter. i want get value it after selected

Answer (score 0):

In hook_form_alter you won't get `$form_state['values']['ANYFIELD']`.
Try `$form_state['build_info']['args'][0]['ANYFIELD']`.

Comment: It doesn't get that either, since `hook_form_alter()` is not invoked when a form is submitted, but before the form is rendered.

Answer (score 0):

textfield always use `fieldname->und->0->value->` sequence in array so,try this.. `$form['ma_so_thue']['und'][0]['value']`;

Comment: This is wrong: `$form['ma_so_thue']` is not an entity field, so you cannot use `$form['ma_so_thue']['und'][0]['value']`. Also the OP is asking for getting the submitted values, which are not in `$form`.

Answer (score -1):

```
$store_name = $form_state->getValue('name')[0]['value'];
```

Some input files are multi-value, so you can just use `getValue('field_name')`.